# Extremely loud crack and mangled sound over S/PDIF using ALSA

Tags: arch-linux, audio, alsa, vlc

Sometimes it seems ALSA on my machine goes completely haywire:

- Flash audio on [Spotify](https://play.spotify.com/) doesn't produce any sound.
- SMplayer plays audio just fine, or doesn't play at all (I've observed the latter today).
- When I start a video in VLC it plays an extremely loud crack, **so loud I'm afraid I'll lose hearing permanently and/or break a speaker**. For comparison, I usually set the receiver volume to 25 when playing music, and 30-35 when watching movies. After detecting the previous two issues, I turned the volume to 6 before playing a video, and even then the crack was painfully loud.
- After the crack, the VLC audio stream is barely audible behind a wall of noise.
- I don't detect any extreme loudness, cracks or other distortion from `speaker-test --device plughw:1,0 --channels 2`.

How can this issue affect only Flash and VLC, but not SMplayer? They all use ALSA and the same sound card, after all. And these symptoms are relatively rare - only detected once every couple weeks or so. A reboot seems to solve them every time, but I would rather have some sort of guarantee that my ears will continue working.

The machine is set up from bare bones Arch Linux, and had as far as I can tell [only the ALSA sound server](https://github.com/l0b0/tilde/blob/8ad25c66ec841e3082ad1e4a48c4c42be742aa37/.bash_history#L1539) installed when the problems were encountered.

The S/PDIF cable is connected to an Onkyo receiver, which is connected to a 5.1 speaker system.

Comment: The digital out from the soundcard is routed/connected to what device? Does this happen for all media played with VLC? What about an MP3? Are you sure you're using alsa and alsa alone - no pulseaudio involved? When smplayer doesn't play, what's the sampling frequency reported for the audio?

Comment: I experienced a similar problem 4-5 times recently. I noticed they arise with skype turned on. I _"patched"_ simply restarting skype.

Comment: Interesting @Hastur. I do use Skype sometimes. I'll keep an eye out for errors after using it.

Comment: @etherfish I have added some more details, but I'll have to get back to you on the rest if I can reproduce the problem again.

Comment: Yesterday I've updated to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Today it did it again. Turned off skype. Disappeared. Turned on again no problem. I remember that one time, after a long run of firefox, and some freeze and restart of the laptop, I was able to fix it just killing the process `/usr/lib/firefox/plugin-container`. Then, after the reloading of the page, I had no problem again. (just all flash were stopped...). I know, just a little bit more soft than a full reboot.